How to build "user" full Android AOSP images for Raspberry Pi 4?
I'm attempting to create a build for my Raspberry Pi 4. I followed the instructions from https://github.com/raspberry-vanilla/android_local_manifest?tab=readme-ov-file and successfully created a correct "userdebug" build using "lunch aosp_rpi4_car-userdebug".
Now, I'm trying to create a "user" build, but I couldn't find that option in the lunch menu. It is possible to create a build of this typer for raspberrypi4?
Thanks in advance for any assistance.
Best regards
